# Seleccionar Fecha Inicio - Fecha Fin FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, fullcalendar

Buenas tardes, mi duda es la siguiente: Al hacer click en "Abrir calendario" necesito obtener una fecha de inicio y un fecha fin y almacenarlas en un input hidden por separado cada una, y que una vez seleccionadas el calendario se haga disabled. Lo que conllevaría a controlar los dos click en el calendario o algo similar. No logro controlar dos eventos distintos para cada fecha.

Codigo:

HTML

```
<label id="abrir">Abrir calendario</label><br>
<input type="text" id="fechaInicio" value=""><br>
<input type="text" id="fechaFin" value="">
<div id="calendar" style="display:none;"></div>
```

JS

```
// Calendar
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $("#abrir").click(function () {

            $("#calendar").css("display", "block");
            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
            dayNames: ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Jue','Vie','Sáb'],
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function (start, end, allDay) {

                var date = new Date(start);
                var day = zerofy(date.getDate());
                var month = zerofy(date.getMonth()+1);
                var year = date.getFullYear();
                var result = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                var fechaInicio = "";
                var fechaFin = "";

                if (result) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
                            title: result,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay,
                        });
                    fechaInicio = result;
                    contador = contador + 1;
                    alert(contador);
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                $("#prueba").val(fechaInicio);
            }
        });
        // Calendar end

        });

function zerofy(number){
if(number < 10)
    number = "0" + number;

return number;
```

}

Enlace a con una demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwyxwnv1/18/)

Gracias de antemano,

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, es que quieres elegir fechas => `Inicio` y `Fin` y mostrarlo en un input y en el momento que se haya elegido no se pueda manipular el evento ni crear ninguno donde se haya ya creado uno, pues...

..aquí te muestro el código (explicación en los comentarios y código simplificado):

```js
$( function() {
            
    $( '#abrir' ).click( function() {
        $( '#calendar' ).css( 'display', 'block' );
        var calendar = $( '#calendar' ).fullCalendar( {
            selectable: true,            
            select: function( start, end ) {

                // Quitamos 1 segundo para que no añade un día más
                var endDate = new Date( end );
                endDate     = new Date( endDate.getFullYear(), endDate.getMonth(), endDate.getDate(), 0, 0, -1 );

                var fechaInicio = dateFormat( start );
                var fechaFin    = dateFormat( endDate );

                // TODO: Validar los datos
                $( '#prueba1' ).val( fechaInicio );
                $( '#prueba2' ).val( fechaFin );

                var titulo = prompt( 'Titulo evento:' );
                var eventData;
                
                if ( titulo ) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: titulo,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    
                    // Destruimos el calendario
                    calendar.fullCalendar( 'destroy' );                

                    // Aqui creamos de nuevo el calendario
                    // sin poder editar y seleccionar
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( {
                      selectable: false,
                      editable: false,
                      events: [eventData]
                    } );
                }             
            }
        } );
    } );
} );

// Función para formatear las fechas para los inputs
function dateFormat( df ) {
    var date  = new Date( df );
    var day   = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year  = date.getFullYear();
    return day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.0/fullcalendar.min.css">
<label id="abrir">Abrir</label><br>
Value fecha Inicio = <input type="text" id="prueba1" value=""><br>
Value fecha Fin = <input type="text" id="prueba2" value="">
<div id="calendar" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder compañero, la funcionalidad que necesitaria es que solo me deje elegir 2 fechas, una de inicio, por ejemplo del dia 02/11/2017 y una fecha fin, por ejemplo 04/11/2017. Y que una vez seleccionadas no pueda crear ningun evento mas. Y que al evento Inicio le ponga el title "Inicio", y al segundo evento le ponga el titulo "Fin", el title se lo deberia poner automatico sin utilizar el prompt. Un saludo!

Comment: @DanielMorenoAlcubilla  - Es lo que hace... y como funciona fullcalendar.. pinchas el dia dónde quieras que empieze y arrastras con el raton hasta el día del fin (sin soltar el ratón) no se si me explico bien... y una vez elegido esas fechas no puedes elegir en esas fechas otro evento... o quieres que que no se pueda elegir ningún evento más? Para eso puedes destruir el calendar y pasar los eventos creados con el método destroy y decir que el calendario no sea selectable

Comment: Cierto, disculpame no sabia que funcionaba asi, fallo mio, si esta todo correcto solo me faltaria que dado el rango por el cliente no pueda volverlo a editar ni crear ningun evento mas como tu dices con el destroy, podrias ilustrarme? Muchas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: @DanielMorenoAlcubilla - Creo que ahora si esta todo como lo deseas... ;) un saludo